# How to make a call via Google Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, audio

I am using [Google Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/) to access my company laptop which has a software installed for making phone calls. Now, I would like to use that software from my pc at home to make a call.

I can hear the audio (it gets duplicated to my pc), but the software does not use my microphone (input), so I am involuntarily muted.

How can I also use my mic as audio input over Google Remote Desktop?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about installable software.